# Is this Possible?? Regarding SP's and Temp tables

Tags: c#, sql, temp-tables

I need to Update table, select rows that were updated, and then get a count on those rows. Is it possible to do this in 1 stored procedure? I'm working in a c# services app and using SQL Server. What's a good alternative if it is not doable.

Comment: Typically I would add a batch number column to the table and include the batch number column in my update statement, so I can reference it when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

After updated you can use [**@@ROWCOUNT**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) for example

```
update tab
  set col = value

select @Val = @@ROWCOUNT
```